# Get Inner text between two tags and get the output into two labels - VB.NET - HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack, innertext

I tried to search for examples and much but nothing seems to work.
so i'm using HtmlAgilityPack and I want to get the inner text between two specific tags.

Example:

```
<br>Terms of Service<br></br>Developers<br>
```

I want to get the innertext where first `<br>` and `<br>` into label1 and the second `</br>` and `<br>` into label2

which will be like

Label1.text = "Terms of Service"
Label2.text = "Developers"

How do i achieve/do/get this?
P.s; I'm not so familiar with HtmlAgilityPack, a code showing how to do this will do better. :-)

Thanks

Comment: Try selecting nodes `"//br"`, looping through the resulting nodes, and setting the label to the `InnerText`.

Comment: I'm  still a beginner in using htmagilitypack, can you like show me in code what you are saying? :)

Comment: im not sure what the heck `</br>` is.  May I ask why your linebreak has a closing tag?  I might have the answer to your problem regardless.  Stand by...

Comment: let me answer my own question.  In XHTML, BR requires a closing tag, but that is not correct.  It should be `<br />`

Comment: @drewlander Sorry about that, it's not my problems as it's not a clean code, the site i'm trying to grab these data is kinda messed up, however if you have an answer for the question, could you help me out? :)

Comment: Please provide a link to the site you are trying to scrape.

Comment: I had to give @Steven-Doggart a point on that because what he said is exactly how you would normally do this with clean HTML and a tag that HAP provides better support for.  I just expanded on his comment with an example to explain why its not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bit dirty, but should work.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

  Dim mystring As String = "<br>Terms of Service<br></br>Developers<br>"

    Dim pattern1 As String = "(?<=<br>)(.*?)(?=<br>)"
    Dim pattern2 As String = "(?<=</br>)(.*)(?=<br>)"

    Dim m1 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(mystring, pattern1)
    Dim m2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(mystring, pattern2)
    MsgBox(m1(0).ToString)
    MsgBox(m2(0).ToString)
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick and worked perfectly! :)
However what i really wanted was how to do this with HtmlAgilityPack, if you or anyone could give me a sample code on how to do this with HtmlAgilityPack that'd be great and i think it'll benefit others who are looking into similar problems :)

Comment: you have me curious if its even possible with HAP, so ill take a look.   Normally I would try to get the innertext by the tag name or ID attribute, but the tags in your situation lack consistency which is why I resorted to two distinct regex patterns.

Comment: Im gonna add my response to that in a second answer so you may see the code and notes.

Comment: Works pretty well, but why it doesn't work with <a> tag? I tried to change all "br" to "a", but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that HAP is not well suited to accomplish your task.  My notes below:

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim mystring As String = "<BR>Terms of Service<BR></BR>Developers<BR>"
        Dim myDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        myDoc.LoadHtml(mystring)
        ' here we notice HAP immediately discards the junk tag </br>
        MsgBox(myDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml)

        ' Below we notice that HAP did not close the BR tag because it only 
        ' attempts to close 
        ' certain nested tags associated with tables ( th, tr, td) and lists 
        ' ( li ). 
        ' if this was a supported tag that HAP could fix, the fixed output 
        ' would be as follows: 
        ' <br>Terms of Service<br></br>Developers<br></br></br>
        ' this string would be parsed as if the last tag closes the first 
        ' and each set of 
        ' inner tags close themselves without any text between them. 
        ' This means even if you changed BR to TD, or some other tag HAP 
        ' fixes nesting on, it 
        ' still would not help to parse this correctly.  
        ' Also HAP does not appear to support XHTML in this .net 2.0 version.  

        myDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = True
        MsgBox(myDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml)

        ' here we put the BR tag into a collection.  as it iterates through 
        ' the tags we notice there is no inner text on the BR tag, presumably 
        ' because of two reasons.  
        ' 1. HAP will not close a BR.  
        ' 2. It does not fix your broken nested tags as you expect or required.  

        Dim myBR As HtmlNodeCollection = myDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//BR")
        If Not myBR Is Nothing Then
            For Each br In myBR
                MsgBox(br.InnerText)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thankyou for explaining this and so i do understand that i'll need a clean code to use htmlagilitypack. Thanks for making me clear about this. :)

Comment: HAP will clean up HTML quite nicely under many circumstances. I use it to clean attributes from tags when converting HTML to PDF with itextsharp for instance.  However your situation is let's say...  Unique.